# How to ignore backslash character in boost::regex_search() function?

Tags: c++, xml, linux, boost

I'm working on C++, I'm getting a regular expression from xml file. And i have to search this regular expression in a long string.
e.g. my regular expression is : `".+myFunction"`

So if i have to  put this regular expression in xml file then i need to use `backslach` character `'\'` before `'.'` in above regular expresssion.
i.e. `"\.+myFunction"`

Now I'm using `boost::regex_search()` function to search above regular expression. But due to additional backslash character, function return false.

So how to ignore the backslach character while using `boost::regex_search()` function??

sample code is as follows:

```
string longString  = "hdh::dfjdj::dfuhgj::myFunction.devide.and"
string regularExp = "\.+myFunction"
const boost::regex searchPattern(regularExp);
if(boost::regex_search(longString, searchPattern))
{
    cout <<"Regular expresssion is found" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think there're other reasons, a single backslash preceding `.` is a no-op. And compiler should've told you so.

Comment: You should have the backslash removed when you read from XML instead of modifying regex code.

Comment: Maybe we misunderstand something... Why do you need to use backslash before the dot if you put it into xml file?

Comment: Thanks is there any function is string which will remove UN-wanted characters from a given string?? @Michael it give error that preceding character is incorrect.

Comment: What gives the error? `.` is invalid character in xml? I think you didn't decribe the situation well...

Comment: What is your requirements ? Isn't your current regex responding ? and there is no need to have a `\.` it means there will be a real `.` in text, whereas `.` means there can be anything

Answer (score 0):

It's not really too clear what you're asking:

- In the XML, `".+myFunction" is perfectly legal, as is.
- If you're trying to match that exact sequence, you'll need to escape
  the backslash twice: once because it has a special meaning in a
  string literal, and a second time because it has a special meaning for
  regular expressions.  You'll also need to escape the quotes, if
  they're part of what you're looking for: `"\"\\\\.+myFunction\""`.
  But if you're trying to match an exact sequence, you don't need
  regular expressions: `std::search` is largely sufficient.
- If you're trying to define a regular expression which matches a
  sequence of one or more characters other than a newline, followed by
  the sequence `"myFunction"`, the string literal to initialize the
  regular expression would be `".+myFunction"`.